# Prevent web page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, web, refresh, greasemonkey

There's a periodic page refresh on this page (http://sosconso.blog.lemonde.fr/2013/07/24/mes-vacances-ne-se-passent-pas-comme-prevu/), I was wondering how it worked and how to prevent it (using greasemonkey for example).

I'm just a user of the site, so all I can do is play with my browser options, or use greasemonkey to alter the javascript.

The page doesn't appear to use the meta refresh tag so I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: Check if the javascript is modifying `window.location` or `window.location.href`. I think there are other ways to refresh the page too.

Comment: I've had that page open for several minutes now.  It does not refresh; what makes you say that it does? (It does make a crap-ton of spammy AJAX calls).  Note that I do have Adblock Plus activated. It may be blocking the offending code.  Install Adblock Plus, if you haven't already. ... That page uses over 23 3rd-party domains! (Not counting blocked ad servers).  I'm not going to dig through all that code looking for potential refreshes; you need to do that.  There is, currently, no blanket way to prevent JS refreshes.  You have to do it case-by-case.

Comment: This question is essentially the same as [your previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18263208/331508).  You should delete that question (flag it, if you don't have delete permission).

Comment: I have adblockplus activated too, along with noscript. I use an extension called tabmixplus that improves the tab user experience so I'm not sure what is part of firefox and what is part of this extension, but I have 2 nice tab features: when the page is loading, a loading bar appears above the tab, showing it's loading something. And when it's finished loading and has new content, its title changes color and becomes red to show it has refreshed. Which I find quite annoying since I didn't ask it to load or refresh anything, so I'd like to disable whatever is regularly being loaded or refreshed

Comment: You need to mention things like *tabmixplus* (or any other, potentially interfering add-ons, scripts, or plugins) in the question!  Are you sure that that is not firing off of AJAX calls?

Comment: I looked at that add-on; it's not something I'm interested in, so I want be installing it just to test for this question.  Try disabling it and seeing if the problem persists.  Try the display options.  Contact the add-on dev for support. [He has a forum](http://tmp.garyr.net/forum/index.php?sid=e226c1453eff716c2bc7519180649aca).

Comment: This is definitely unrelated to this add-on, it's a very popular add-on (one of the most), and I only get this for this page. The add-on is just there to show me that some content is still loading now and then. I'm sure that you could get to the same conclusion with other tools, such as dev tools (network monitoring or something like that). But it's not that add-on that keeps it loading.

Comment: I don't use that add-on; I turned off a lot of my crud-blocking and monitored that page with Firebug for at least 15 minutes.  It did not refresh.  That add-on, or your interpretation of its display, is a VERY likely culprit.

Comment: Okay, I trust your judgement, I'm not an expert. So assuming that tabmixplus is doing that, how could I check why it is doing so? It is amongst the 10 most used add ons, with firebug and adblock, so I doubt that it's full of bugs, but maybe I found one ? How to make sure? Maybe something else, perfectly normal, could trigger that behaviour, and I just don't know what it is?

Comment: First, disable that add-on and see if the problem goes away.  It's easy to disable and then later re-enable add-ons (but often requires a Firefox restart).

Comment: Well given that I am using the plugin's features to describe my problem (mainly, the fact that the plugin adds an extra progress bar over the tab when it's loading something, and turns the tab title font color to red when something has changed on the page), then when I disable the plugin, it obviously goes away, but it doesn't mean that there still isn't something trying to load, or whatever else it is that could have triggered this plugin's behaviour.

Comment: From what you describe, the plugin may be reacting to AJAX, which is NOT a refresh.  This may be normal behavior for that plugin for a site such as that one, that uses lot's of AJAX to spam the user.  Use the forum link, I gave above and discuss it there.